# Select all text not in div elements using xpath?

Tags: xpath

how can i select only text which is not in div tags?

eg.

```
<div>
    <div>not this</div>
    1<br/>
    <div>not this</div>
    1<br/>
    1<br/>
    <div>not this</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>not this</div>
    2
    <div>not this</div>
    2   
    2   
    <div>not this</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>not this</div>
    3
    <div>not this</div>
    3   
    3   
    <div>not this</div>
</div>
```

results: {'1/n1/n1/n','2 2 2','3 3 3'}

Comment: Do you mean not in a second level `div`?  Everything you have posted is in a `div`

Comment: Apologies, yep, not in a second level div.  Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and simple one-liner XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted nodes. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//text()[normalize-space()][../node()[not(self::text())]]
```

**Meaning**: *any not whitespace only text node having at least one sibling node*

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
div/text()[string-length(normalize-space()) > 0]
```

This expression, when evaluated with the parent of the provided XML fragment as the context node, selects all non-white-space-only text-node children of any `div` child of the context node.

**Here is complete verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each select=
   "div/text()[string-length(normalize-space()) > 0]">
    "<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML fragment** (wrapped in a top element to become well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <div>
        <div>not this</div>
        1<br/>
        <div>not this</div>
        1<br/>
        1<br/>
        <div>not this</div></div>
    <div>
        <div>not this</div>
        2       
        <div>not this</div>
        2
        2          
        <div>not this</div></div>
    <div>
        <div>not this</div>
        3       
        <div>not this</div>
        3
        3          
        <div>not this</div></div>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
"
        1"


    "
        1"


    "
        1"


    "
        2       
        "


    "
        2
        2          
        "


    "
        3       
        "


    "
        3
        3          
        "
```